# Cocoa Swift: Simulate key press by when clicking a button

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, macos-high-sierra

I'm trying to simulate a keypress by clicking a button on my app. I've scoured stackoverflow and there are a few examples, but none of them seem to work for me. I can see the print statement in the console, but no character is pressed when I switch to a text editor. Here is what I have:

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    // Set delay to allow me to switch to a text editor
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
        print("pressing keyboard button")
        self.keyboardKeyDown(key: 6)
        self.keyboardKeyUp(key: 6)
    }
}

func keyboardKeyDown(key: CGKeyCode) {
    let source = CGEventSource(stateID: .hidSystemState)
    let event = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: source, virtualKey: key, keyDown: true)
    event?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
}

func keyboardKeyUp(key: CGKeyCode) {
    let source = CGEventSource(stateID: .hidSystemState)
    let event = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: source, virtualKey: key, keyDown: false)
    event?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
}
```

Comment: tFound this SO answer. Seems pretty similar to what you've done
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484330/simulate-keypress-using-swift Did you try to open a text field inside the app, to see if the keypress is received here.

Comment: Switch off sandboxing.

Comment: Thanks Wileke, that worked. If you pop it in an answer I'll select it.

Comment: Here's a very good answer: [How to post a Quartz Event after Swift application launch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47213929/4244136).

Comment: So I can't simulate keypress if I have sandboxing on? Is there really no other way? Because without sandboxing, app will not pass Apple Review stage.